# Calling non thread class from thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

**My Problem**:

I want to run a method from a Thread, which is no Thread but might take some time to execute (e.g. waiting for server response). It is important that my none thread method is in another class (the classes are Objects which are used in other classes too).

If you do this as in the example code, the whole program will pause for 10 seconds, but I want it to continue with other program code.

Is there a good way of doing this?

**My code**:

*MyThread.java* (`extends Thread`)

```
public Foo foo;

public void run() {
    foo.bar();
}
```

*Foo.java*

```
public void bar() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        // Represents other code that takes some time to execute
        // (e.g. waiting for server response)
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And a *main* method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyThread t = new MyThread();
    t.foo = new Foo();
    System.out.println("Starting!");
    t.run();
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to call `run()` on the Thread, you want to call `start()`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `MyThread` extends `Thread`, you need to call `start()` not `run()`.

Calling `run()` is just calling a method synchronously.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyThread t = new MyThread();
    t.foo = new Foo();
    System.out.println("Starting!");
    t.start(); // change here
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

`start()` actually starts an OS thread to run your code on.

Answer (score 0):

Use start() rather than run() on your thread. Or else it will be just like the main thread calling a method of another thread which means you are calling wait() on the main thread itself.

Answer (score 0):

don't call run() method directly.

call start() method instead of run() method.

when call run() method directly

this thread go to main stack, and it run one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class MyThread extends Thread{

         public Foo foo;

         public void run() {
            foo.bar();
         }
 }

class Foo{

     public void bar() {
      try {
         boolean responseCompleted = false;
         boolean oneTimeExcution = false;
         while(!responseCompleted){
              if(!oneTimeExcution){
                       // Represents other code that takes some time to execute
                   oneTimeExcution = true;
              }
              if( your server response completed){
                      responseCompleted  = true;
              }
         }
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
     MyThread t = new MyThread();
      System.out.println("Starting!");
     t.start();        
     System.out.println("Done!");
}
```